# Import Error for models in Django while importing model in validators file

Tags: python, django-models

I am getting an error
File "D:\DjangoProjects\StudentExam\website\Student\validators.py", line 2, in  from .models import Branch

ImportError: cannot import name 'Branch' from 'Student.models' (D:\DjangoProjects\StudentExam\website\Student\models.py)

For the statement  “ from .models import Branch “ , written in validators.py file.
Even when these both files are in the same app it's giving an error. I don’t understand what’s going wrong.

I even tried “from Student.models/website.models import branch” but then it is showing unresolved reference Branch.

Directory Structure is as follows:-

```
StudentExam
  -venv
  -website
     -Student
        -migrations
        -__init__.py
        -admin.py
        -apps.py
        -models.py
        -tests.py
        -urls.py
        -validators.py
        -views.py
     -website
        -__init__.py
        -settings.py
        -urls.py
        -wsgi.py
     -db.sqlite3
     -manage.py
```

validators.py :-

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import Branch

def increment_id():
    last_branch_id = Branch.objects.all().order_by('id').last()
    new_branch_id = last_branch_id + 1
    return new_branch_id
```

models.py :-

```
from django.db import models
from .validators import validate_sem,cie_out_of,ese_out_of,increment_id

class Branch(models.Model):
    branchID = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key = True, serialize = True, validators = increment_id())
    branchName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join('{} = {}'.format(key, value) for key, value in self.__dict__.items() if key != "_state")
```

Comment: You have a circular import. You would need to have these in the same file. But note that you *do not want to do this at all*, you should just use the automatic primary key which will already be auto-incrementing. Doing all this is pointless. Especially as a validator is for validating, not for creating new values anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: use **`AutoField`** instead, or do not specify a primary key at all: Django will automatically construct one named `id`.

You make a *circular import* here: your `models` module depends on your `validators`, and vice versa.

You can however lazily load the `models` module, by importing it in the `increment_id`:

```
# app/validators.py

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def increment_id():
    from .models import Branch
    last_branch_id = Branch.objects.all().order_by('BranchId').last().BranchId
    new_branch_id = last_branch_id + 1
    return new_branch_id
```

In your models, you can then work with:

```
# app/models.py

class Branch(models.Model):
    branchID = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True, serialize=True, default=increment_id)
```

Note however that this is *not* a validator, you here have a default value. Furthermore you should *not* have to write that: Django has an [**`AutoField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield), that:

> An IntegerField that **automatically increments** according to
>   available IDs. You **usually won't need to use this directly**; a
>   primary key field will automatically be added to your model if you
>   don’t specify otherwise. See Automatic primary key fields.

You can thus better define this as:

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    branch_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # ...
```

According to the [*PEP-8 Style Guidelines*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it is furthermore advisable to name attributes with *`lowercase_with_underscores`*, so `branch_id` instead of <s>`branchId`</s>.

Furthermore it makes typically no sense to name the primary key something else than `id`. By prefixing it with `branch_id`, you can make less use of *duck typing*. So it might be better to omit that field completly, as the [documentation on *Automatic primary key fields* says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> By default, **Django gives each model the following field**:
>
> ```
> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
> ```
>
> This is an auto-incrementing primary key.
>
> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify
>   `primary_key=True` on one of your fields. If Django sees **you've
>   explicitly set `Field.primary_key`**, it **won't add the automatic
>   `id` column**.

So unless you have a good reason to specify one yourself, you can just list the data columns:

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    # ...
    # other non-pk fields
```